# Django Get html id for widget while rendering another

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms

I've been working on a few projects that require me to know the html id of a Django widget while rendering another widget, and so far I have found no sane way of doing it. Here's on of many use cases:

Say we have Field A and Field B both in the same django form.
Now say that field A takes a username and field B is an autocomplete text field that takes the value of field A and makes an ajax call using said value. The logic for the autocomplete would be in the render method of field B's widget but I have no access to field A's widget from field B's widget and I need access in order to get field A's widget html id and target it using jquery like so `$("#field_a_id").val()`. So far the only way I found to do this is the following

```
class DjangoForm(forms.ModelForm):

    field_a = forms.CharField()
    field_b = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel   

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DjangoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # HACK !!!
        field_a_id = self['field_a'].id_for_label
        self.fields['field_b'].widget.attrs.update({'field_a_id': field_a_id})
```

by doing that then I can easily get the id using jQuery, but It feels a little hackish.
So my question would be, is there a better way to do this ?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If the sole purpose of the field A is to serve as a filter for field B - for example, if field A is State and field B is City - you should use only one field (City, because State can be inferred from City) and write a custom Django widget.

Comment: I wish it were that simple :), but in this case I need both fields because field A's value is crucial to field B's value and can't be inferred :(

Comment: Perhaps you will get better advice if you provide a more concrete, real-world example, xará.